# Execute httpSample conditionally JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to test a REST method for saving an object. In order to have the ability to save it I need to request an authToken that is updating each 100 seconds.

Right now I have a thread containing both requests , and the login request is executed each time the saving does. How can I make the login execute once at the start of the thread and then each 100 seconds ?

P.S. I've tried separating it in 3 threads , one for the initial login , the other with a loop and a 100 seconds timer and finally the one with the actual test. It does work ,but it seems like a bad solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
|-Login
|-Loop n times
    |-Save
```

n being number of times that will be just about less than 100ms?

or

```
|-If login valid?
|   |-NO: Login
|
|-Save
```

option 3:

```
ThreadGoup1
|- Login
|- Beanshell update shared token
|- Constant throughput timer

ThreadGroup2
|- Beanshell fetch shared token
|- Save
```

A [constant throughput timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) allows you to run at a set throughput. Once every 100 seconds is 0.6 samples per minute, I'm not certain you can do fractions, but even 1 sample a minute should work for you.

Comment: Looping for n times isn't a really good option , if my response times will change I will end up with a smaller set of sample data.

Comment: The second option looks better , I can't actually check if the login is valid , but I can check the last samples response code , if the response failed I can authenticate again. This does do the trick , but still it's a workaround and not the exact solution I would like to implement.

Comment: added an option #3, probably more aligned to what you're looking for. But in most cases 1 or 2 would suffice and they're simpler.